# Is there a site for estimations of the value of objects?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site where one could ask for estimations of the value of objects?
(E.g. how much one could ask for something on a site like eBay.)

Comment: No, there is no SE site where a question like that would fit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within the Stack Exchange network, no. A couple of observations:

1. How much something is worth depends (too much) on what a person is willing to spend on it (i.e. it's primarily opinion-based).
2. Since it will vary based on lots of factors (the state an object is in, if there's currently a hype about it, the country you are located, the currency you trade in), questions aren't really valuable for future readers. At Stack Exchange, we love reusable questions.
3. A single site covering these kind of questions would probably need a very broad audience to answer all questions. Valuating a household appliance is a lot different from valuating a painting.

I'd suggest to find similar objects, check at which price they're sold, and/or sell via an auction system. If it's a popular item, you'll probably get a fair price because of the interaction between the bidders; most sites offer the option to set a minimum price.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I kind of figured that such a site wouldn't fit the "style" of SE. But who doesn't ask will never know :)